# Additive characters of a vector space isomorphic to the linear dual?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field $k$.

Denote by $\widehat{V}$ the group of additive characters $V \to \mathbb{C}^*$ and $V^*=Hom_k(V,k)$ the linear dual. Fix a non-trivial additive character of the field  $\chi : k \to \mathbb{C}^*$. Consider the following map:

$$V^* \to \widehat{V},\alpha \mapsto \{v \mapsto \chi(\alpha(v))\}$$

I'd like to **show that this is an isomorphism**. I had **no problem showing it was injective**. To show **surjectivity** I used my knowledge of the charater of $k$ to write everything explicitly and it worked in the end. I think this should be a lot simpler though. In particular I think **there should be a proof** that works for continuous characters with $k$ local field. So:

> What's the most natural way to show that this is a surjection? (using the least amount of explicit calculations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group of additive characters of a finite abelian group is of cardinality equal to that of the group you started with. Likewise $V^*$ has cardinality equal to that of $V$. So for any function $V^* \longrightarrow \widehat{V}$, injectivity and surjectivity are equivalent.

Comment: I suppose you mean the dimensionality of $V$, not its "cardinality"

Comment: @EwanDelanoy No, I meant cardinality. It's a fin. diml. vs over a finite field.